# FATAL: The --user is not supported for non-root users when try to execute gitlab-runner status

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, fatal-error

when try to execute gitlab-runner status
FATAL: The --user is not supported for non-root users

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmTSX.png)

Can you please help me to execute this command without appending sudo (sudo gitlab-runner status)

I want to run the command gitlab-runner status without appending the sudo keyword.

Comment: You can add your user to that group using the usermod command. This should grant necessary permissions to execute the command without sudo.

Comment: @codeapplied, Can you please provide me the sample command to add gitlab-runner as sudo user.